# Unix timestamp conversion

Tags: mysql, timestamp, unix

How can I output my Unix timestamps to human readable GMT?

```
SELECT
      category
      ,fullname
      ,shortname
      ,idnumber
      ,startdate
      ,visible
      ,timecreated
      ,timemodified
  ,count( my.id ) AS mydata
FROM mdl_mytable
JOIN mycontext ct ON ( ct.my = cat.id )
LEFT JOIN myjoin ra ON ( mycontext = cat.id )
WHERE ct.mynumber =10000000
GROUP BY shortname, fullname, .category
      ,.idnumber
      ,.startdate
      ,.visible
      ,.timecreated
      ,.timemodified
ORDER BY myorder ASC
```

Note: The query has been changed for security reasons.

Comment: You might need to show your actual query (at least the part with FROM_UNIXTIME)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL support a [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)(...) function :-)

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(1433433155)
```

And the other way around, [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Applying it to your example, assuming `timecreated` and `timemodified` are those Unix timestamps:

```
SELECT
      category
      ,fullname
      ,shortname
      ,idnumber
      ,startdate
      ,visible
      , FROM_UNIXTIME (timecreated)
      , FROM_UNIXTIME (timemodified)
  ,count( my.id ) AS mydata
FROM mdl_mytable
JOIN mycontext ct ON ( ct.my = cat.id )
LEFT JOIN myjoin ra ON ( mycontext = cat.id )
WHERE ct.mynumber =10000000
GROUP BY shortname, fullname, .category
      ,.idnumber
      ,.startdate
      ,.visible
      , FROM_UNIXTIME (timecreated)
      , FROM_UNIXTIME (timemodified)
ORDER BY myorder ASC
```

Comment: Sorry but I was a bit quick to say yes it worked.  Actually I have no clue how to integrate this with my SQL :(, it ran with no errors but the two timestamp fields I applied this too are now missing in the result set

Comment: Error FROM_UNIXTIME and UNIX_TIMESTAMP database.UNIX_TIMESTAMP does not exist